# Overpass API: retrieve all buildings that contain indoor data

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

As the title says, I want to get all build features (`nwr[building]`) where there is indoor data (`nwr[indoor]`) available for them.

My starting point for this search would be like this one:

```
[out:json];(area["name"="Dresden"];)->._;(nwr[building](area._););(._;>;); out;
```

which obviously gets me all the buildings in the given area, not only the ones which contain indoor data.
But the problem seems to be that there is no information on a building feature whether it contains such data or not, so there must be a more sophisticated way to do this query.

Please note: I am not looking for a solution to get the indoor data itself (which is done easily).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a good solution but you can query for all indoor features and then search for buildings that are connected to them or intersect with them:

```
nwr["indoor"](area._)
way(around:0)["building"];
```

The second part is really slow, so better don't try it on large areas.

See an example here: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1e6N

Comment: For ways, it would be better to use "objects in areas": https://dev.overpass-api.de/blog/way_based_areas.html#covers (introduced in 0.7.57 release)

Comment: @mmd Thanks for the hint. Feel free to add an answer with the improved query. Unfortunately I don't get what needs to be changed.

Comment: Thank you guys! I created a solution based on your hints, which should be working well for my purposes:` (area[...];)->._;
(nwr[indoor](area._););
(nwr[building](area._););`